# plugin.media erro

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Estou tentando utilizar o *Media Plugin for Xamarin and Windows* com o *Visual Studio Community 2017*. Um aplicativo android que deverá ter a capacidade de tirar algumas fotos.

Segui as seguintes orientações:

Em Resources, adicionou uma pasta chamada `'xml'` e dentro dela criei um arquivo por nome `file_paths.xml` com o seguinte código:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
      <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
    </paths>
```

Em seguida, abri o arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` e adicionei o seguinte código:

```
<application android:label="ReporOnLine.Android">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>     
    </application>
```

No arquivo AssemblyInfo.cs adicionei:

```
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]
```

Quando tento depurar o aplicativo usando o *Genymotion* com *Google Nexus 4 - 5.0.0 API 21*, ou meno no meu smartphone, gera o erro conforme imagem em anexo.

Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Substitui a seguinte linha:

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
```

por

```
android:authorities="com.companyname.ReporOnLine.fileprovider"
```

Limpei a solução e recompilei, tudo funcionou perfeitamente.